# Deprecation warnings from generated sources not suppressed even if specified in lint.xml

Tags: android, lint, android-tiramisu

In our Android project, targeting API 33 caused a lot of deprecation warnings. In particular, the generated code for navigation args are still using deprecated usages of Bundle.get (see this issue I filed: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/237725966)

The warnings look like this: `'get(String!): Any?' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java`

To get around this, I specified the following in our `lint.xml` file:

```
    <issue id="Deprecated" severity="ignore">
        <ignore path="build" />
    </issue>
```

This did not work. Changing the path so that it uses globbing to something like:

```
<ignore path="**/build/generated/source/navigation-args/**" />
```

This doesn't work as well.

Anyone knows how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just to update my question, this issue is supposed to be fixed already in Navigation 2.5.1, see this [comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/237725966#comment13) in the issue tracker. As to how I resolved this, I didn't wait for the said fix and instead, refactored our app to only use primitive arguments as navigation arguments